# Combining headers of multiple Excel files into the body of a single Excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I have more than 1000 Excel files in a folder. I want to copy the **first row** in each file into another single Excel file. How I do that?

To illustrate, I want to do this:

```
File_1.xls: row 1 -> File_Master.xls: row 1
File_2.xls: row 1 -> File_Master.xls: row 2
File_3.xls: row 1 -> File_Master.xls: row 3
File_4.xls: row 1 -> File_Master.xls: row 4
.
.
.
File_1000.xls: row 1 -> File_Master.xls: row 1000
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? In other words, which specific part of the task are you having a problem with? Looping though files in the folder? Opening each file? Copying the first row?

Comment: All three, actually. I am a total newbie... please bear with me.

Comment: How to loop through files in a folder: http://www.vadriano.com/excel-vb/2007/04/21/how-to-loop-through-files-in-a-folder/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

```
Sub FirstRow()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim strFilename As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim wbMaster As Workbook
    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
    Dim wbFiles As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 1
    Set wbMaster = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsMaster = wbMaster.Sheets(2)
    strPath = "C:\path\to\your\files\"
    strFilename = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")

    Do While strFilename <> ""
        Set wbFiles = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strFilename, False)
        wbFiles.Sheets(1).Rows(RowIndex:=1).Copy
        wsMaster.Cells(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:=1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
        wbFiles.Close (False)
        strFilename = Dir
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

A couple of things to note:
- You'll want to change the `Sheet(x)` references to the appropriate values for your needs
- Ensure there is a "\" at the end of strPath when you put in your own path
- I've turned `DisplayAlerts` to false during the execution to avoid a pop-up on every file asking if you want to clear the clipboard or not.